# How can I draw a graph like this in a computer program?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, charts

Here is a hand drawing of the type of graph I need to draw. The actual one has about 16 events, some are clustered but others are further away.

[image]

I don't know how to do this in Excel. I need to show information with each point, on the point itself! I prefer that a short vertical line appear rather than a point. The text describes what the point represents and the value represents a value on the horizontal axis. As you can see, the vertical axis is redundant here.

Can Excel make such graphs? Do I need to use Python? I prefer that it can be done in Excel or Python but if a better alternative exists, please let me know.

I don't want to use paint to just manually draw this since it will most likely change several times as the values on the horizonal axis for each event will change as I continue my work on this subject.

Comment: this website might be helpful for you in asking that https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily accomplished in Excel.  All you need to do is use your data to create an XY/Scatter Chart and then format as appropriate.  Using the Scatter Chart, your horizontal values will be proportionally accurate.  You can also use vertical error bars to replace your markers (dots).  And Excel now allows you to use a range of cells for labels, so you can have your Event labels (or whatever else you choose) as part of the chart.  You can also completely remove the vertical axis if you'd like (since it's redundant).

1. Create your data table (i.e. an Excel table, created using `Insert>Tables>Table`).
   [image]
2. Create a blank XY/Scatter chart (do this by `Insert>Charts>Scatter` while you have a blank cell on the worksheet selected)
3. Select data for your chart (with chart selected, right-click and choose `Select Data` from context menu).
   **Name:** Anything you like
   **Series X:** your X column
   **Series Y:** your Y column
4. Format as desired.  To match your sample, I did the following:
   Changed Y axis (removed labels, changed max value)
   Changed X axis (removed labels)
   Changed series (add data labels, add vertical error bars (for lines), turn off markers)
5. Here's the final version:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide a sample about your problem?

In Excel Chart, you can use ***Data Labels*** to help display values:
[image]

Comment: I did not know about data labels. OK, so you can think of problem like this. I am trying to show on a graph at what time events A,B,C,D ... occur. Thus every point represents an event that occured and the time that it occured at. It is important that the name of the event and the it occured be clear on the graph as the precise value is VERY important.